# I am testing growth in 4 different hydrogels (and in 4 different medias). Which test should I use to determine which hydrogel was best overall?

Tags: survival, multivariate-analysis, multilevel-analysis, percentage

I am testing *in vitro* ovarian follicle growth in 4 different hydrogels. I have also tested 4 different medias with each hydrogel. I need to use a statistical test to determine which hydrogel was best overall (in all medias). My data is in percentage survival (%). Which test should I use?

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep track of the total number of observations in each case, not just the percentage survival. If you only have 5 observations, an estimate of 20% survival (1 of 5) isn't very reliable. If you have 5,000 observations, an estimate of 20% survival (1000 of 5000) would be highly reliable.

With the actual counts in hand, a simple way to model this would be a binomial logistic regression. If you really want to know "which hydrogel was best overall (in all medias)," then you would use a simple additive model with the types of hydrogel represented as one 4-level categorical predictor and the media as another 4-level categorical predictor. In R you could model this as the following generalized linear model:

```
mod1 <- glm(c(success, fail) ~ hydrogel + media, data=yourData, family = binomial)
```

where the data would be in 16 rows, with each row having labels for the `hydrogel` and `media` and the number of associated `success` and `fail` observations.

If you suspect that the relative performances of hydrogels might differ among media, you could include an interaction term between those predictors:

```
mod1 <- glm(c(success, fail) ~ hydrogel * media, data=yourData, family = binomial)
```

This [UCLA web site](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/other/dae/) has examples of how to perform logistic regression with several software systems.